# Excel VBA Save a Download in Internet Explorer

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer, save

I have the following snippet of VBA code:

```
  Set ClassObj = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")

 ClassObj(76).Click
```

After it clicks the webpage, a little pop up box appears at the bottom of the web page asking me if I want to save or open the file. I would like to use VBA to click the Save button, so that it will go to my Downloads folder. How do I do this?

Comment: What's the href value on the link?  If it's a direct link then it would be easier to download that resource directly instead of clicking on the link in the browser.

Comment: Although unreliable, one of your only options is to use SendKeys to throw [alt]+S at the dialog. There is no other control over this dialog that I am aware of although a better alternative is the [URLDownloadToFile function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775123.aspx).

Comment: You should provide an URL where possible or enough HTML to produce an [MCVE]